# What font is the one in this picture?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I’m trying to make a couple edited photos and found this font that I would really wanna use. Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions and tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 5):

It is **Nimbus Sans Round Bold**

- [MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/nimbus-sans-round/bold/)
- [Typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts/nimbus-sans/details/nimbus-sans-round-bold)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here's what i found, hope it can help

[image]